Is there a way to run npm install without installing dependecies?
For many npm packages, running npm install <package name> installs the package and also its dependencies.
For example, when running npm install eslint, the response is added 89 packages in 12s, all of those packages are present in the node_modules directory and non are used directly in my code.
My question is: is there a way to avoid installing all of those dependencies and have eslint function normally?
